# Retrieve rendered output within same page

Tags: java, jsf

I have a page that is rendered correctly. On this page I have a button and I wish to save a selection of the page as html when the user click on the button.

I saw in MyFaces and Tomahawk that they added the tag Buffer that allows you to render into a buffer, does anyone know of anything similar for standard JSF?

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing like that is available in the standard JSF implementation, not in Mojarra nor MyFaces. You can however just install and use Tomahawk on Mojarra. It's a common misconception that it would work on MyFaces only.